# I can't log out in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I was logged in Android Studio **Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2** with some working google account but when a project was finished my account was deleted. So, when I hover a mouse over an profile icon in Android Studio - I see an email of that account, but when I press on that icon I get an error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toString()" because "url" is null
```

[image]

How to log in Android Studio with another google account?